# What is UI version 16?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016

I’m currently porting a SharePoint Server 2013 site collection to Office 365/SharePoint Online. While uploading master pages, I find the UI version option 4, 15 and 16. This implies that there is a new version on SharePoint in the process of being released to SharePoint Online. It was also confirmed on the European SharePoint Conference that a new Server version was being developed. However, SharePoint Online would get this new version first.

[image]

This is the first time I’ve come across UI version 16. Is it what I think it is or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Cloud Service Office 365 is being updated regulary. The current SharePoint 2013 has the Version 15 and the next Generation of SharePoint is the Version 16. So in Office 365 you will find the first new Frontend Features of the next SharePoint On Premise Generation. Also in the SDK for SharePoint 2013 and Office 365 you will find the first new functions and already the 16-Hive.

But in your case it doesn't matter whether you check UI-Version 15 or 16. In my case i noticed no difference. I think it is more interessting how the new default masterpage in the UI-Version 16 will look like.

Try whether you see a difference if you check the UI-Version 16. I am interessted in your Feedback :)

All upcoming or currently rolled out updates for Office 365 you will find at the Office 365 [Roadmap](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-365-roadmap-FX104343353.aspx)! There are coming new nice functionalities in the next time.

I hope i could help you. Otherwise let me know it!

Comment: Thanks for giving me further insights. I didn't know there was a public roadmap to follow. Looks like I have some reading up to do on what is to come!

Answer (score 4):

It's the preparation for SP2016. Microsoft will release new SharePoint upgrades/features on O365 before the on-premise versions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is not new that the cloud is updated regularly and Office 365 has seen "16" references for quite a while now.

I personally don't see the online versions as a specific version, but as the "online" version which may map to SharePoint 2013 at one time, but gradually evolve either to a new version of SharePoint, or as its own cloud product.

Master pages

```
<%@ Page language="C#"   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

More:

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-version-16-0-0-1810/